# Conditional routing not working in Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, module, conditional-statements, router

In my dev build in my angular project, In the child module's routing file I am doing something like below,

```
const routes = window.innerWidth > 768 ? desktopRoutes: mobileRoutes;
```

Then I am passing these routes to `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`

The dev build works like a charm, however, when I create a prod build and deploy it, this thing fails to work and only loads the mobileRoutes, Irrespective of the screen resolution.

Any suggestions or alternatives I should look into are welcome

Note: that desktop route components extend Mobile components, just adding the info if that helps!

Comment: Did tried to rebuild the application env prd ,in local?

Comment: Yes , I have tried

Comment: I don't know much experience of angular, however, I believe where application initializes. I guess it ngOnInit() you can calculate the width there and then save in some service or something.  Then use where you register the routes

Answer (score 6):

It's because in prod build, AOT (Ahead of time compilation) is used, pre-compiling your routes. So, your routes return the false value: mobileRoutes.

There are some workarounds

1. Using `router`: [resetConfig(config)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5754#issuecomment-438654162) You should pass as parameter the new configuration, as described in [resetConfig](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig) documentation, changing only the required routes.
2. Using guards with [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

---

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  if( window.innerWidth > 768 ){
    return true; // return desktopRoute
  }

  this.router.navigate(['main/']);  // mobileRoute
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I think using resetconfig will reset the whole router, but what should be done if I want to change/switch the routes in the feature module only.

Comment: No because you should pass as parameter the new configuration, changing only the required routes. Check this https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig